# Ortho imagery overlapping a top of Hillshade

Tags: arcgis-desktop, image-mosaic, hillshade, aerial-photography

I have a hillshade mosaic dataset made from DEM and I also have another mosaic dataset made with a aerial photo.
I will like to overlapping so I can see both layer together, however I don't want to transparency aerial photo mosaic because I lose quality of aerial photo.

I tried https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/imagery/an-alternative-to-overlaying-layer-tints-on-hillshades/

I also tried http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/wkflw-combining-hillshaded-dem-with-a-scanned-map.htm

Both failed. Is there a any suggestion about it? Anyone tried it?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "failed." Also, we have something someone gave us that seems to do this well, but they did not explain the how of it. I have not tried the methods in the two links but this looks interesting.

Comment: Both method didn't turn out what I expected.

Comment: Which is? What were you expecting if not in transparency? Do you have an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just Tried second method, the first try didn´t work as expected, but second try did result, instead of run functions at the end, I just click on apply everytime I made a function in order to see what´s the parcial result